# How do I beat the Gaming in the 3rd house

Tags: candy-box-2

In candy box 2, how do I win the gaming in the 3rd house with the key that I just unlocked from the squirrel. I have tried to buy all the swords and shields to defeat the monsters but it just doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about the Super RPG game playable on the gaming machine (the one that costs 10 candies to play)

This game has no ending as there is [no floor limit](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Super_RPG)